# Akka clustering - force actors to stay on specific machines

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I've got an akka application that I will be deploying on many machines. I want each of these applications to communicate with each others by using the distributed publish/subscribe event bus features.

However, if I set the system up for clustering, then I am worried that actors for one application may be created on a different node to the one they started on.

It's really important that an actor is only created on the machine that the application it belongs to was started on.

Basically, I don't want the elasticity or the clustering of actors, I just want the distributed pub/sub. I can see options like singleton or roles, mentioned here http://letitcrash.com/tagged/spotlight22, but I wondered what the recommended way to do this is.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no feature in Akka which would move your actors around: either you programmatically deploy to a specific machine or you put the deployment into the configuration file. Otherwise it will be created locally as you want.

(Akka may one day get automatic actor tree partitioning, but that is not even specified yet.)

Comment: hmm, but the singleton manager will start actors on other nodes. Does the partitioning that's about to be released not work in a similar way. It looks like it does in the docs. I'll need to re-read it though I'm probably wrong. Otherwise, what is the point in clustering?

Comment: @Nick See this example which shows how to ensure that specific actors are only created on one machine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213196/akka-actors-scaling-across-jvms-and-servers-and-example-at-akka-io/26450349#26450349

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the best way to use elastic clustering. But we also consider on the same issue, and found that it could to be usefull to spread actors over the nodes by hash of entity id (like database shards). For example, on each node we create one `NodeRouterActor` that proxies messages to multiple `WorkerActor`s. When we send message to `NodeRouterActor` it selects the end point node by lookuping it in hash-table by key `id % nodeCount` then the end point `NodeRouterActor` proxies message to specific `WorkerActor` which controlls the entity.