# Akka cluster-sharding: moving actor shards based on communication patterns

Tags: scala, akka, sharding, akka-cluster

I am building an open-source distributed economic simulation platform using Akka (especially the remote and cluster packages). A key bottleneck in such simulations is the fact that communication patterns between actors evolve over the course of the simulation and often actors will end up sending loads of messages over the wire between nodes in the cluster.

I am looking for a mechanism to detect actors on some node that are communicating heavily with actors on some other node and move them to that other node.  Is this possible using existing Akka cluster sharding functionality? Perhaps this is what [Roland Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/958431/roland-kuhn) meant by "automatic actor tree partitioning" is his answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196968/akka-clustering-force-actors-to-stay-on-specific-machines) SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move shards around according to your own logic is doable by implementing a custom `ShardAllocationStrategy`.

You just have to extend ShardAllocationStrategy and implement those 2 methods:

```
def allocateShard(requester: ActorRef, shardId: ShardId, 
  currentShardAllocations: Map[ActorRef, immutable.IndexedSeq[ShardId]])
  : Future[ActorRef]

def rebalance(currentShardAllocations: Map[ActorRef,
  immutable.IndexedSeq[ShardId]], rebalanceInProgress: Set[ShardId])
  : Future[Set[ShardId]]
```

The first one determines which region will be chosen when allocating a new shard, and provides you the shards already allocated. The second one is called regularly and lets you control which shards to rebalance to another region (for example, if they became too unbalanced).

Both functions return a Future, which means that you can even query another actor to get the information you need (for example, an actor that has the affinity information between your actors).

For the affinity itself, I think you have to implement something yourself. For example, actors could collect statistics about their sender nodes and post that regularly to a cluster singleton that would determine which actors should be moved to the same node.